# vis.js large nodes overlapping in hierarchical mode

Tags: javascript, vis.js

[image: sample]

Is it possible to have nodes in vis.js in hierarchical layout without overlaping on X axis?

I tried to add  options:

```
    var options = {
        layout: {
            hierarchical: {
                direction: "UD",
                sortMethod: "directed"
            },
            physics: {
                solver: "barnesHut"
                ,barnesHut: {
                    avoidOverlap: 1
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase `layout.hierarchical.nodeSpacing` for the initial layout.

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1 with lage text'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2 with lage text'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Node 3 with lage text'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4 with lage text'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5 with lage text'}
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5}
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var options = {
  layout: {
    hierarchical: {
      direction: "UD",
      sortMethod: "directed",
      nodeSpacing: 200  // <-- !!!!!!!
    }
  },
  physics: false
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.17.0/vis.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.17.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi mojoaxel,

Of course I can  increase nodeSpacing, but that sets constant space value between centers of nodes. When I have nodes with different kind of description text some small, some large, I would like to have the minimum space value that can devide each node and do not allow them to overlap.

Comment: That is not possible at the moment. Please accept this answer and create a feature request on github. Thx.

Comment: Actually I wrote the algorithm in  Java that do  that, and  calculate spacing for each node and then create joison model that can be loaded in JoinJS to draw the diagram. It works, but now I need  pure Javascript solution, and I'm searching if something like that exists out of the box.
Seems that I would need to convert my Java algorithm to Javascript code and do the same trick there.

Comment: @MaksimSirotkin did you finally port your Java code to JavaScript? or did you find another solution? I have exactly the same issue and as far as I can tell, it is still not possible to do this natively in vis.js network.

Comment: "is still not possible to do this natively in vis.js network"

I came to the same conclusion and made algorithm that calculates positions.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be

```
myVisOptions = {
    layout: {
        hierarchical: {
            direction: "UD",
            sortMethod: "directed",
            shakeTowards: 'roots'
        }
    },
    physics: {
        // https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html
        enabled: true,
        hierarchicalRepulsion: {
            avoidOverlap: 0.99
        },
        stabilization: {
            iterations: 2000,
            updateInterval: 100
        },
        solver: 'hierarchicalRepulsion'
    },
    nodes: {
        margin: 8,
        shape: 'box',
        font: {size: 20},
        color: {
            background: 'white',
            border: '#ffc468',
            hover: '#ffc468',
            highlight: '#ffc468'//, '#bd6500'
        },
    }
};
```